# Center li number of a ol list

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a `ol` list. This list is fill with `li` that contains text that can be on multiple line. What I want to do is to center the number that mark the position in the list.

Ex:

```
<ol>
   <li>
       Text in multiple line
   </li>
</ol>
```

Will do :

```
  1. Text in
     multiple line
```

The '1' in the previous example is the thing that I want to position at the middle center. Is it possible. If yes, how can I do that.

Comment: Do you mean have the number centered _vertically_?

Comment: Obviously, the OP wants to vertically align the ordered list numbers so that they are positioned in the middle of their corresponding multi-lined list items.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this may be what you're looking for:

```
<style>
    li span {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>

<ol>
    <li>
      <span>Text in <br />multiple lines</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Text in one line</span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I really like this simplistic approach, although some adjustment on positioning is needed for modern browsers for one-liners, the position is slightly off and i've not been able to fix it without nudging it up with "position:relative"....

Comment: Oh, you're right, I see that happening in Chrome and Safari; Firefox looks fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<ol>
<li>Text in </br>multiple line</li>
</ol>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8kLu/)

Comment: No downvote, but this is not even close to being what the OP asked for.

Comment: Yup. You are right. I deserve a downvote. The "1" in this case is generated content right? The only thing that can be done with it is use the list-position property.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that the list-position property is that the number is now part of the text (if I use the inside value), so now the text goes under the number. Is that a way to fix that?

Answer (score -2):

If your list element should come to center try this

```
<ol>
   <li style="text-align:center;">
       Text in multiple line
   </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I think what he wants is for the number of the LI to be centered vertically between the top and bottom of the multiline content.